# gpointing-device-settings isn't working - ubuntu 17.04

Tags: touchpad, 17.04, synaptics

gpointing-device-settings isn't working. It doesn't work when I click 'apply' and it doesn't work after a restart. I'm trying to turn off mousepad tapping on my laptop, a dell 5577. I am using ubuntu and gnome for my desktop. I am up to date with 17.04. I have tried the following with synclient:

synclient TapButton1=0 TapButton2=0 MaxTapTime=0

but nothing happens. I also tried the above as sudo, and I tried removing and inserting the psmouse module with modprobe.

Comment: I don't think that gpointing has worked for quite some time. Uninstall it.

Comment: ok. synclient still doesn't work. how would I get more info about my touchpad?

Comment: You could try `touchpad-indicator`.

Comment: ok. I use touchpad-indicator and disable tap events, but it doesn't change the way the touchpad works.

Answer (score 1):

I created this file called `85-my-libinput.conf` . I put it at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` . Apparently the synaptics driver has a lexical filename numbered higher than `40-libinput.conf`, at `50`, but this touchpad requires libinput to work. My script just defines the desired driver at the `85` lexical position in that directory. After restarting the Mousepad System settings program shows extra options, one of them for turning off tapping.

```
    # put at /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/

    Section "InputClass"
            Identifier "touchpad"
            MatchIsTouchpad "on"
            MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
            Driver "libinput"
            Option "Tapping" "off"
    EndSection
```